# open classic personalization settings in control panel

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

In windows 10, control panel is quite depreciating. Now when we open it and click Personalization and Appearence then it opens the applet in Settings app. How to open the classic settings in Control panel? It will be also better to create shortcut on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In run box, use:

```
shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageColorization
```

And to create desktop shortcut use:

```
Explorer.exe shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageColorization
```

`-Micr...` part is optional, upon removing it also works.